# Retry endTurnWithNextParticipants

Tags: ios, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

I want to handle the error case where `endTurnWithNextParticipants` fails. I therefore store match data by calling the `cacheFailedEndTurnWithNextParticipants` method at the end of this post. I provided the function only for reference.

The problem is that I don't know how I shall restore the data in the uncache method. How can I load the `GKTurnBasedPlayers` for the nextParticipants list? I use `GKPlayer::loadPlayersForIdentifiers` now, but I get the following warning:

```
"/Users/eternity/Documents/Xcode/DominationSK/DominationSK/GKMatchCache.m:134:74: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray<GKPlayer *> * _Nullable' to parameter of type 'NSArray<GKTurnBasedParticipant *> * _Nonnull'"
```

How can I load `GKTurnBasedParticipants` from ID's?

Shall this retransmitting be done in another way?

```
-(void)uncache
{
  if (_cache.count > 0)
  {
    NSDictionary *d = _cache[0];
    [_cache removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchWithID:d[MATCH_ID]
                withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch * _Nullable match, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error == nil)
                  {
bad load method --> [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:d[PARTICIPANTS]
                                  withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<GKPlayer *> * _Nullable nextParticipants, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                    if (error == nil)
                                    {
                                      NSNumber *timeout = d[TIMEOUT];
warning -->                          [match endTurnWithNextParticipants:nextParticipants
                                                            turnTimeout:timeout.longValue
                                                              matchData:d[DATA]
                                                      completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error){
                                                      // This is not finished
                                                      }];

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                      [self addToCache:d]; // TODO: Add time to live
                                    }
                                  }];
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    [self addToCache:d]; // TODO: Add time to live
                  }
                }];
  }
}

// Just for reference
-(void)cacheFailedEndTurnWithNextParticipants:(GKTurnBasedMatch*)match
                                 participants:(NSArray<GKTurnBasedParticipant*>* _Nonnull)nextParticipants
                                  turnTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout
                                    matchData:(NSData* _Nonnull)matchData
                                        error:(NSError* _Nonnull)error
{
  if ([self shallBeCached:error])
  {
    NSMutableArray *playerIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *p in nextParticipants)
    {
      [playerIds addObject:p.player.playerID];
    }
    NSDictionary *d = @{MATCH_ID : match.matchID,
                        PARTICIPANTS : playerIds,
                        TIMEOUT : [NSNumber numberWithLong:timeout],
                        DATA : matchData};

    [self addToCache:d];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the participants from the match, and then retrieve player IDs from that array, and finally update the participants attribute in the match.